# How proof functions are combined in Coq

Tags: coq

In the following simple theorem the proof is given directly in the form of a proof function. I'd like to understand how the two terms, parenthesized to reflect my concept, combine into a final proof function that returns the expected type.

```
Lemma simple : forall i, i <= S i.
Proof
  fun i => (le_S i i) (le_n i).
```

It seems as if the `(le_S i i)` constructor term returned a function which then would  accept `(le_n i)` as a parameter. Could someone be kind to explain how proof function combination works here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might want to read ([https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curry–Howard_correspondence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curry%E2%80%93Howard_correspondence)).

Basically in Coq proofs are functions which take evidence (in form of a witness) for some proposition as arguments and produce evidence (a witness) for a new derived proposition.

If you do `Check le_S.` you get

```
le_S
     : forall n m : nat, n <= m -> n <= S m
```

So `le_S` is a function which takes two nats and a witness for `n <= m` and produces a witness for `n <= S m`.

In you example `le_n i` is a witness for `i <= i`.

Please note that the `->`symbol has the same meaning for usual functions like `Check Nat.add.`

```
Nat.add
     : nat -> nat -> nat
```

as for proofs. `a -> b` in both cases means function from type `a` to type `b`.

Answer (score 2):

`(le_S i i)` is a value that is a function. It expects as argument another value, here `(le_n i)`, of type `(i <= i)`, since the type of `le_n` is `forall n : nat, (n <= n)`. The value of `(le_S i i)` applied to this argument is of type `(i <= S i)`, as you could see from the type of `le_S`. The `forall` in the lemma explains the `fun` in the final value used to define `simple`.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, What I can't see from its definition is how `le_S i i` is a function. Could you briefly explain that.

Comment: If you look at the type of `le_S` in the documentation or directly in Coq, you'll see it is `forall n m : nat, (n <= m) -> (n <= S m)`. Once passed the two arguments `i` and `i` for `n` and `m`, you get a function value to which you can pass `(le_n i)`.